# Can Rasa chatbot initiate a conversation?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I'm planning to deploy the bot based on rasa with a monitoring engine. So if something goes wrong, I would like bot to start the conversation with a specific user. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to do so, would be to send a user message from your monitoring system to your [input channel](https://rasa.com/docs/core/connectors/). So you basically mimic the user initiating the conversation. Note that I directly specify the intent using the `/` as prefix. 
Start Rasa Core with the REST api exposed:

```
python -m rasa_core.run -d models --enable-api
```

Then you can send messages to it, e.g.:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "sender": "<sender_id_of_your_user>",
  "message": "/inform_about_failure"
}'
```

Comment: Great,I will try this

Answer (score 1):

@Tobias's solution is the "old way" still valid to manage external events in a pull-based chatbot engine (not just RASA), when we want to push notifications to `sender_id`.

With the current RASA release, to run the RASA Core server the cli command is:

```
rasa run --debug --enable-api -m models
```

And the `curl` request @Tobias specified is still valid with current RASA version:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "sender": "<sender_id_of_your_user>",
  "message": "/inform_about_failure"
}'
```

On the other hand, the suggested way by RASA now (version 1.9.7), is to use [external events management](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/reminders-and-external-events/).

That way you can specify also the entities along with the intent to be triggered, as the example shows:

```
curl \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -X POST \
 -d '{"name": "EXTERNAL_dry_plant", "entities": {"plant": "Orchid"}}' \ 
 http://localhost:5005/conversations/<sender_id_of_your_user>/trigger_intent
```

BTW in RASA, `sender_id` and `conversation_id` are different names for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. But `rasa_nlu` got nothing to do with this, you will be sending a `push_message`from your backend to the chat client from there `rasa_nlu` picks up the conversation.