# How to start Rasa conversation with chatbot message?

Tags: chatbot, rasa

I just started to learn implementing a chatbot with Rasa and I am wondering how to make the chatbot start the conversation.

I read this thread: [Can Rasa chatbot initiate a conversation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454544/can-rasa-chatbot-initiate-a-conversation)
and the docs: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/reaching-out-to-user/#reaching-out-first

But I am wondering if it is also possible to manipulate the `ActionSessionStart` default action. For example I tested the following code but still the chatbot waits for user input after startup.

Do I do it wrong or is this just not possible?

```py
class ActionSessionStart(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_session_start"

    async def run(
      self, dispatcher, tracker: Tracker, domain: Dict[Text, Any]
    ) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        # the session should begin with a `session_started` event
        events = [SessionStarted()]

        events.append(ActionExecuted("utter_greet"))

        return events
```

Comment: This can be achieved from the frontend, may I know which frontend UI you are using to communicate with rasa?

Comment: I don't work with Rasa any more. It was just a short termed project. But thanks for the inquiry!